# Converting from Swift string to const char*

Tags: c, swift, swift3, swift4

I'm trying to pass a const char * to an old C library converted from a Swift string in Swift.

This is the C function I'm calling:

```
artnet_node artnet_new(const char *ip, int verbose) { ...
```

how can I convert a Swift string to this const char type? It works when I pass ipAddress like this:

```
internal var ipAddress = "192.168.1.43"
```

but dit does not work when I pass it like this

```
internal var ipAddress:String = "192.168.1.43"
```

I need this in a function where I need to specify the type:

```
internal func setupArtnode(ip:String) -> Int{
```

I tried using AnyObject instead of String but that doesn't work either.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add clarification on what doesn't work- compilation or execution, and any associated error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why but this code is working. This passes a string to a C function expecting a const char* which seems to be the same as a unsafePointer.

```
internal func setupArtnode(ipAddress:String) -> NSInteger{
    let cString = self.ipAddress.cString(using: String.defaultCStringEncoding)!
    let newString:String = NSString(bytes: cString, length: Int(ipAddress.characters.count), encoding:String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue)! as String
    let key2Pointer = UnsafePointer<Int8>(newString)

    node = artnet_new(key2Pointer, Int32(verbose))     // VERBOSE : true(1) , false(0)
...
```

Answer (score 11):

You should be able to pass a `String` directly to a C function expecting `const char *` and it will be automatically converted to a null-terminated UTF-8 string:

```
let string = "string"
let node = artnet_new(string, 1)
```

See [Interacting with C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html)  for more information.  Here is the relevant excerpt:

> When a function is declared as taking an UnsafePointer argument,
>   it can accept any of the following:
>
> - A String value, if Type is Int8 or UInt8. The string will automatically be converted to UTF8 in a buffer, and a pointer to that
>     buffer is passed to the function.

Comment: for some reason the function wont take the argument and takes the default value, i updated the question with some more info

Comment: your quote got me to use UnsafePointer<Int8> which seemed to work, I added my working code. thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Simple way for Swift 3

```
var ipAddress: String = "192.168.1.43"
var verbose: Int = 1
artnet_node artnet_new((ipAddress as NSString).utf8String, verbose)
```

Comment: While using sqlite3 API sqlite3_bind_text() with swift, I was seeing memory corruption and weird results if the String was directly passed. `(ipAddress as NSString).utf8String` fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what your Swift array contains. In any case, you need to convert your Swift array to an array of `Int8`:

```
let str = "Hello world"
let cArray = str.cString(using: .utf8)

artnet_new(cArray, 1)
```

Comment: I'm sorry i mistyped, I'm trying to change a single string to a const char :s, edited the question