# Trouble formatting a path for the Linphone SDK in Swift

Tags: c, swift, macos, linphone-sdk

Thanks in advance for the help!

I am trying to record calls using the **Linphone SDK** in Swift on Mac OS, and am having trouble passing a path into the function:

```
func linphone_call_params_set_record_file(_ cp: OpaquePointer!, _ path: UnsafePointer<Int8>!)
```

that works correctly (the SDK is written in C, though I am accessing it using Swift and a *bridging header*). The Linphone SDK works properly, and I can make and receive calls programmatically, with full audio support.

In trying to invoke the call recorder, I pass this function a path (`pathtofile`), such as:

```
let pathtofile = "/Users/Alex/Safety/1.wav"
```

where I would like to store the recording file.

```
func SafetyNetAVRecorderInitializer(pathtofile: String) -> Bool {
    // Convert pathtofile to UnsafePointer<Int8>.
    let cpathtofile = (pathtofile as NSString).utf8String
    let path = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(mutating: cpathtofile)

    // Actually begin call recording.
    if currentcall != nil {
        let currentcallparameters = linphone_call_get_current_params(currentcall)
        linphone_call_params_set_record_file (currentcallparameters, path)
        linphone_call_start_recording(currentcall)
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

No runtime errors are encountered on `linphone_call_params_set_record_file()`, but when I try to invoke `linphone_call_start_recording()`, the recording does not begin, and an error is printed in the console that reads:

> ortp-error-linphone_call_start_recording(): no output file specified. Use linphone_call_params_set_record_file().

How can I correctly pass a valid path to `linphone_call_params_set_record_file()`? I have tried directly passing a plain Swift `String` instead of an `UnsafePointer<Int8>` to no avail. Am I just misunderstanding how paths are formatted in C?

For reference, the SDK method source is:

```
void linphone_call_params_set_record_file(LinphoneCallParams *cp, const char *path){
if (cp->record_file){
    ms_free(cp->record_file);
    cp->record_file=NULL;
}
if (path) cp->record_file=ms_strdup(path);
}
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let cpathtofile = (pathtofile as NSString).utf8String! // Unwraps!
...
inphone_call_params_set_record_file(currentcallparameters, cpathtofile)
```

Comment: That did not work, unfortunately-- thank you for your help, though!

Comment: @kmypwn You should be really able to [directly pass](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41308592/819340) `pathtofile: String` as well. Maybe your bug is elsewhere... :-(

Comment: I suspect that it is... hopefully someone with more intimate knowledge of the Linphone SDK can provide some insight.

Comment: For what it's worth, here is the SDK function linphone_call_params_set_record_file(): `void linphone_call_params_set_record_file(LinphoneCallParams *cp, const char *path){
    if (cp->record_file){
        ms_free(cp->record_file);
        cp->record_file=NULL;
    }
    if (path) cp->record_file=ms_strdup(path);
}`

Comment: @PauloMattos, Thanks this worked for me. But I am facing issue in playing records file. currently it is recorded in .mkv file. Can you suggest an alternate way?