# How to convert string to char* in swift?

Tags: swift

I am trying to use python interpreter in swift. But it is written in C and thus I have created a bridge between ObjC and Swift. Method in C accepts char * and when I try to pass string to method it says that it accepts only UnsafeMutablePointer. I am trying to convert it like this

```
let str = "Hello" as NSString
var buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>(str.utf8String)
```

but Swift compiler says,Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer' with an argument list of type '(UnsafePointer?)'. What is the proper way of using C data types in Swift and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/27876179/1187415.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a duplicate from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308409/converting-from-swift-string-to-const-char). You can simply use

```
let str = "Hello"
let buffer = str.cString(using: .utf8)
```